# need to remove the content from the tag using pattern-Matcher using java

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove the content from the tag

```xml
<reference id="">..</label></reference>

<?insert_start author="0017598" timestamp="20220704T111051+0530"?>
<reference id="">Yoon et al., 2014L.W.YoonT.N.AngG.C.NgohA.S.M.ChuaFungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase productionBiomass Bioenergy672014319338Yoon, L. W., Ang, T. N., Ngoh, G. C., Chua, A. S. M., 2014. Fungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase production.Biomass Bioenergy.67, 319-338.</label/></reference>
<reference id="">Xue et al., 2015Y.P.XueM.JinA.OrjuelaP.J.SliningerB.S.DienB.E.DaleV.BalanMicrobial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stoverRSC Adv.520152872528734Xue, Y. P., Jin, M., Orjuela, A., Slininger, P. J., Dien, B. S., Dale, B. E., Balan, V., 2015. Microbial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stover.RSC adv.5, 28725-28734.<label/><reference>
<?insert_end?>
```

**Source code :**

```java
  public static void main(String[] arg) 
      {
          String strXmlTxt = "<?insert_start author=\"0017598\" timestamp=\"20220704T111051+0530\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<reference id=\"\">Yoon et al., 2014L.W.YoonT.N.AngG.C.NgohA.S.M.ChuaFungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase productionBiomass Bioenergy672014319338Yoon, L. W., Ang, T. N., Ngoh, G. C., Chua, A. S. M., 2014. Fungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase production.Biomass Bioenergy.67, 319-338.</label/></reference>\r\n" + 
                "<reference id=\"\">Xue et al., 2015Y.P.XueM.JinA.OrjuelaP.J.SliningerB.S.DienB.E.DaleV.BalanMicrobial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stoverRSC Adv.520152872528734Xue, Y. P., Jin, M., Orjuela, A., Slininger, P. J., Dien, B. S., Dale, B. E., Balan, V., 2015. Microbial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stover.RSC adv.5, 28725-28734.<label/><reference>\r\n" + 
                "<?insert_end?>";
            
System.out.println("strXmlTxt"+strXmlTxt);
Pattern correctionRegexp = Pattern.compile
("<?oxy_insert_start author=\"(.*?)\" timestamp=\"(.*?)\"?>(.*?)<?oxy_insert_end?>");

Matcher correctionMatcher = correctionRegexp.matcher(strXmlTxt);

while (correctionMatcher.find()) {
    String correctionTag = correctionMatcher.group();
    Pattern startTagRegex = Pattern.compile("<reference id=\"\">(.*?)</label/></reference>>");
    Matcher startTagMatcher = startTagRegex.matcher(correctionTag);
    String startValue = startTagMatcher.find() ? startTagMatcher.group(1) : "";
    
    System.out.println("startValue "+startValue);
}

}
```

but it is not working fine. i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: startvalue :  Yoon et al., 2014L.W.YoonT.N.AngG.C.NgohA.S.M.ChuaFungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase productionBiomass Bioenergy672014319338Yoon, L. W., Ang, T. N., Ngoh, G. C., Chua, A. S. M., 2014. Fungal solid-state fermentation and various methods of enhancement in cellulase production.Biomass Bioenergy.67, 319-338.

Comment: Startvalue : Xue et al., 2015Y.P.XueM.JinA.OrjuelaP.J.SliningerB.S.DienB.E.DaleV.BalanMicrobial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stoverRSC Adv.520152872528734Xue, Y. P., Jin, M., Orjuela, A., Slininger, P. J., Dien, B. S., Dale, B. E., Balan, V., 2015. Microbial lipid production from AFEX™ pretreated corn stover.RSC adv.5, 28725-28734

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the substring() method instead of regex?

Comment: take a look at XML parsers instead: https://www.edureka.co/community/11046/best-xml-parser-for-java